# Violin plot: one violin, two halves by Boolean value

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization, violin-plot

I am toying around with seaborn violinplot, trying to make a single "violin" with each half being a different distribution, to be easily compared.

Modifying the simple example from [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_violinplots.html) by changing the x axis to `x=smoker` I got to the following graph (linked below).

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True)

# Load the example tips dataset
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# Draw a nested violinplot and split the violins for easier comparison
sns.violinplot(x="smoker", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
               split=True, inner="quart", data=tips)
sns.despine(left=True)
```

[image: This is the resulting graph]

**I would like that the graph does not show two separated halves, just one single violin with two different distributions and colors.**

Is it possible to do this with seaborn? Or maybe with other library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are specifying two things for the x axis with this line `x="smoker"`. Namely, that it plot smoker yes and smoker no.

What you really want to do is plot all data. To do this you can just specify a single value for the x axis.

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True)

# Load the example tips dataset
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# Draw a nested violinplot and split the violins for easier comparison
sns.violinplot(x=['Data']*len(tips),y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
               split=True, inner="quart",
               palette={"Yes": "y", "No": "b"},
               data=tips)
sns.despine(left=True)
```

This outputs the following:
[image: output]